# Geopandas' "to_crs" function won't work with Orthographic projection

Tags: python, maps, geopandas, orthographic

I am trying to use Geopandas to plot a map of the world in the Orthographic Projection, as shown in [TowardsDataScience](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-handle-map-projections-properly-in-python-bcbff78895c4) and tried to use the "to_crs" function with the crs of "EPSG: 9840" which is the EPSG of the Orthographic Projection, but it gives the error message **"Invalid projection: EPSG: 9840: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create: crs not found)".** Geopandas [claims that it supports EPSG codes](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/projections.html#coordinate-reference-systems), but this one doesn't work. Is this just because Geopandas specifically doesn't support *this* code, or is there something wrong with my code?

I have searched through [the websites](https://epsg.io/?q=) [included in the tutorial](https://spatialreference.org/) and none of the results there worked either.

Answer (score 0):

- **geopandas** depends on **pyproj** for CRS projections.  (It is installed when you install **geopandas**)
- **pyproj** installs a database of CRS when installed
- below works on my system.  Have included **geopandas** and **pyproj** versions
- my environment is not at all custom and includes >6500 epsg CRS codes

```
# EPSG: 9840

import geopandas as gpd
import pyproj

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
world = world.loc[world["continent"].eq("Europe")]
world = world.to_crs("epsg:9840")

codes = [crs.code for crs in pyproj.database.query_crs_info(auth_name="EPSG")]
print(f"{pyproj.__version__}, {gpd.__version__}  number of epsg CRS defined:{len(codes)}")

[crs for crs in pyproj.database.query_crs_info(auth_name="EPSG") if crs.code=="9840"]
```

#### output

```
3.3.0, 0.10.2  number of epsg CRS defined:6525

[CRSInfo(auth_name='EPSG', code='9840', name='UCS-2000 / LCS-35 Kirovohrad', type=<PJType.PROJECTED_CRS: 'PROJECTED_CRS'>, deprecated=False, area_of_use=AreaOfUse(west=29.74, south=47.74, east=33.9, north=49.25, name='Ukraine - Kirovohrad region (oblast).'), projection_method_name='Transverse Mercator')]
```

Comment: From what I can tell, this should work, but it doesn't. things of note are
- my version of pyproj is only 3.2.1
- when I print len(codes) it returns only 6456

Comment: It’s worth uninstalling and reinstalling pyproj

Comment: I tried to install pyproj 3.3.0, but when I used the requirments.txt method(I am using pyCharm by the way) it said that 3.2.1 was the latest version, when [this website](https://pypi.org/project/pyproj/) says that 3.3.0 is the latest version.

Comment: I have discovered that I only have Python 3.7, and I need at least python 3.8 to install 3.3.0, so once I have done that, I will check back with my results.

Comment: ok - amended answer as well,  new last line should give you list length 1 with the required CRS definition.

Comment: Sorry for being so long in getting back to you. I successfully updated everything, and when I ran the code, it worked, in a manner of speaking. Rather than displaying and accurate orthographic projection of the earth, it displayed this strange image:

EDIT: don't know how to include images in the comments.. do you know?

Comment: I know of no way to put an image in a comment ...  maybe ask a new question with your "working" around the way the projection looks.   this question was specific to CRS projection was failing

Comment: Ok, I could try that.

Comment: new question posted