# Geopandas Orthographic Projection displays wrong

Tags: python, maps, geopandas, orthographic

Follow-up question to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71758853/geopandas-to-crs-function-wont-work-with-orthographic-projection) so that I can include an image of what the output is.

This is the output when I run the following code, cleaned up to only include important parts:

[image: This]

```
import pyproj
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

currentProjection = "Orthographic"
nel_path = gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres")
g_path = "myDirectory/ne_110m_graticules_10/ne_110m_graticules_10.shp"


class Projections:
    class Mercator:
        world = gpd.read_file(nel_path)
        cities = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_cities"))
        graticules = gpd.read_file(g_path)
        graticules = graticules.set_crs("EPSG:4326")


def createprojection(crs, name):
    class Thing:
        world = Projections.Mercator.world.to_crs(crs)
        cities = Projections.Mercator.cities.to_crs(crs)
        graticules = Projections.Mercator.graticules.to_crs(crs)

    setattr(Projections, name, Thing)


createprojection("EPSG: 9840", "Orthographic")


def plot_map(gdf1, gdf2, gdf3, name, unit):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 10))
    gdf1.plot(ax=ax, color="lightgray")
    gdf2.plot(ax=ax, color="black", markersize=10, marker="o")
    gdf3.plot(ax=ax, color="darkgray", linewidth=0.5)
    ax.set(xlabel="X Coordinate -" + unit, ylabel="Y Coordinate -" + unit, title=name)
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    projection = getattr(Projections, currentProjection)

    plot_map(projection.world, projection.cities, projection.graticules, currentProjection, "Metres")
```

I did modify things up to an extent so that it would be easier to switch between projections, which is part of my end goal, but it still works exactly the same way as in [the tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-handle-map-projections-properly-in-python-bcbff78895c4)

anything not part of the tutorial was added for ease of use, and if you switch the `currentProjection` variable at the top to "Mercator" it still works perfectly fine.

These are the versions of libraries I have:

Python:3.10, Pyproj:3.3.0, Geopandas:0.10.2, matplotlib:3.5.1

Comment: update your question with code that you have used to generate that image

Comment: updated to include code and library versions

Comment: I figured out that the EPSG 4978 displays the world from a top view, but do you know hoe to make it appear in at any angle?